# BUILD target from make file consisting of source files, shared library( .so) and static library (.a)

Tags: c, unix

I have .so and .a files which are made in (32 bit using -m32 )in a 64 bit architecture. 
But while running the final make file it is showing incompatible .a to make a.out.

Can you let me know the probable mistake ?? Thanks in advance

its showing:  skipping incompatible ./bin/libBasicDirectoryClient.a when searching for -lBasicDirectoryClient

however i have checked using objdump -f libBasicDirectoryClient.a | grep ^architecture
and its showing "architecture: i386, flags 0x00000011:"

Note: My platform is 64 bit

Comment: Going to need more to go on than that - can you add the compile call used for `libBasicDirectoryClient.a` and for the target executable?

Comment: VERBAL=@ </br>
LD=g++ </br>
CUR_BIN_DIR:=$(CUR_DIR) </br>
LDFLAGS+= </br>

CUR_OBJECTS:=$(call SRC_2_OBJ,$(CUR_SOURCES),$(CUR_OBJ_DIR)) </br>
LIB_DIRS=-L$(TEST_DIR) </br>
LIB_DEPS= $(call ADD_LINKER_OPT,--whole-archive) $(TEST_LIB_DEPS) </br> $(call ADD_LINKER_OPT,--no-whole-archive) </br>

 


$(VERBAL)$(LD) -o $(CUR_BIN_DIR)/$@ $(LDFLAGS) $(CUR_OBJECTS) </br> $(LIB_DIRS) $(LIB_DEPS)  </br>

Comment: @Oliver Mattews    Probably the problem may be libexpat.so in my system is 64 bit compatible

Comment: Although useful (and should be added to the question rather than added as a comment), I was more after the /actual/ g++ invocations rather than the build rules (which are potentially incomplete - e.g. LDFLAGS is only added to.